# Unable to access network shares and network printers even if I am able to ping them

Tags: networking, printer, network-shares

I can't see network shares neither print to network printers even if I am able to ping the network resourcers. Printer are installed correctly but then when I send a page to printer it simply doesn't print. For network shares while I can ping the machines hosting the share when i try to access the share enter

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a common problem with the Windows Firewall.  Details on how to allow file and printer sharing through the Windows firewall can be found here:

http://ecross.mvps.org/howto/firewall.htm

Comment: It is something more complicated. I have completely disabled Windows firewall and tryied it again. Same result: i can ping DAVES-PC but then for \\DAVES-PC i get the message: "Windows cannot access \\DAVES-PC".

Comment: Have you disabled the firewall on daves-pc?

Comment: Yes. All my colleagues can access the share.

Comment: Try restarting the `Workstation` service in the windows Services control panel

Comment: I have just found that the shares that I cannot access are on domains that are different from the one I'm joined to

Answer (score 0):

Some of the necessary Windows services may be stopped or disabled on your system. To repair the possible wrong configuration, you can run Troubleshooter via Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center > Troubleshoot problems > Shared Folders if you are on Windows Vista/7.